# How to parse a Json API extract images URLs and return them

Tags: jquery, json, api

I'm new to using APIs and I am completely blocked with the use of an API I have to use in one of my projects. 
Here's the API I have to use : https://api.dev.navigart.fr/890/artworks.json
My goal is to build a webapp that allows its users to search for items within that API and then save them in their "personal space".

How do I search for the input's value in that API and then just extract the images' URL to display them in a div using Jquery for instance ? The API is so complex I'm completely lost :(

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to use a json viewer that displays JSON tree structure. I use: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Once you get that done the rest is easy (here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9b0a8fsv/). Make an .ajax call to the API and in the 'success' do:

```
var results = data.results;

      for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
          console.log('i: ' + i);
          var article = $('<article/>');
          article.attr('id', results[i]['_id']);
          // iterate through medias
          var medias = results[i]['_source']['ua']['medias'];

          if (medias){
              console.log(medias.length);
              for (var j=0; j<medias.length; j++){
                  // url format: http://images.navigart.fr/{size}/{file_name}
                  var imageURL = medias[j]['url_template'];
                  console.log(imageURL);
                  // replace params
                  imageURL = imageURL.replace('{size}', paramSize);
                  imageURL = imageURL.replace('{file_name}', medias[j]['file_name']);

                  // add to article
                  article.append($('<img/>').attr('src', imageURL));
              }
          }

          list.append(article);

      }
```